# I deleted 2 files on my github file but not commited. But when i write git status, it says deleted

Tags: github, git-untracked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlGSh.png)

I dont want to delete those files. What should i do? I scratched my github username beacuse of my school.

Comment: The screenshot has a suggestion to try `git restore`. Maybe try that for restoring the files? :)

Answer (score 0):

`git restore FILE_NAME` should do the trick